# Get the value between the apostrophes in C#

Tags: c#, split, apostrophe

I want to extract the value between the apostrophes, for example from this string: `package: name='com.app' versionCode='4' versionName='1.3'` This is what "aapt" returns when developing android apps. I have to get the values `com.app`, `4`, and `1.3`. I'd appreciate any help :)
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883873/get-value-between-two-characts-in-string), however this is VBA.

Comment: I already know stirng.Split, however I don't wat to split it at the apostrophe, I want the value between it.

Comment: Use the apostrophe as the splitting character, and you can get the values between the apostrophes.  Your array will be `{"name=", "com.app", " versionCode=", "4"...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should work on all cases, assuming that the `'` character only occurs as the enclosing character for values:

```
string input = "package: name='com.app' versionCode='4' versionName='1.3'";
string[] values = Regex.Matches(input, @"'(?<val>.*?)'")
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(match => match.Groups["val"].Value)
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: @P1nGu1n: I amended it slightly to improve its robustness. Use the new version instead.

Comment: Thanks again for the solution! But what's the difference?

Comment: The previous version would break if there was any whitespace between the `=` and the opening `'`. For example, it would not work on `name = 'value'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string strRegex = @"(?<==\')(.*?)(?=\')";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"package: name='com.app' versionCode='4' versionName='1.3'";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

[RegEx Hero sample here.](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=60d63481-e5dc-41b8-8c63-0631b4f9522f)

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested, here's a translation of that VBA you linked to:

```
public static void Test1()
{
    string sText = "this {is}  a {test}";
    Regex oRegExp = new Regex(@"{([^\}]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
    MatchCollection oMatches = oRegExp.Matches(sText);
    foreach (Match Text in oMatches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Text.Value.Substring(1));
    }
}
```

Also in VB.NET:

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim sText = "this {is}  a {test}"
    Dim oRegExp = New Regex("{([^\}]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)
    Dim oMatches = oRegExp.Matches(sText)
    For Each Text As Match In oMatches
        Console.WriteLine(Mid(Text.Value, 2, Len(Text.Value)))
    Next
End Sub
```